# How to get horizontal scrollbar which will work in Internet Explorer?

Tags: html, firefox, scrollbar, explorer

I made a Facebook app, but my picture is a bit more wider, than 520 px. I wanted to add a horizontal scrollbar to my html file, but I have a problem. I used this code in my html file:

```
<div style="overflow-x:scroll; width: 1040px; height: 523px;">

</div>
```

This is working perfectly with Firefox, but there isn't any scrollbar in Explorer. Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE needs some weird combination for it to actually work in the way you want it to.

Have a look here: http://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html

Try giving it overflow-y:hidden before doing overflow-x:scroll

Also try overflow-x:auto after doing overflow:hidden or overflow-x:hidden.

Comment: Thank you! overflow-y:hidden; overflow-x:visible; did the job! :)